# Make Go tests independent from each other (mutation of global vars)

Tags: unit-testing, go, initialization

Given I run the following tests:

```
const unchanged = "unchanged"

var myField = unchanged

func TestChangeField1(t *testing.T) {
    if myField != unchanged {
        t.FailNow()
    }
    myField = "changed"
}

func TestChangeField2(t *testing.T) {
    if myField != unchanged {
        t.FailNow()
    }
    myField = "changed"
}
```

The second test will fail because the variable has already been changed in the other test.

I know there are workarounds like using a test suite which offers hooks to reset this value to the initial state between the tests. But first this means some overhead, and second I feel that the whole behavior is surprising, so I can't really be sure that everybody in my project remembers that and complies.

Is there is a more straight-forward solution for `go test`, like a flag I haven't found yet?

Comment: The best fix would be to *stop using global variables*. They make code harder to test and more error-prone.

Comment: The problem isn't `go test`, the problem is the code mutating package state. If you absolutely must do that (it does happen from time to time), simply defer a cleanup function.

Comment: I agree that global variables are not the preferable way to go and I try to avoid it where it makes sense. That said there are cases where your global variables almost act as constants, but you might need to change them in unit tests. Of course there are ways around that, but it feels like a legitimate use case for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@JimB mentioned this in the comments but if you need to run clean up after a test case you can register functions that run after each test with `t.Cleanup`.

```
package main_test

import (
    "testing"
)

const Default = "default"
const SomethingElse = "something else"

var someVar = Default

func TestOne(t *testing.T) {
    t.Cleanup(resetState)
    if someVar != Default {
        t.FailNow()
    }
    someVar = SomethingElse
}

func TestTwo(t *testing.T) {
    t.Cleanup(resetState)
    if someVar != Default {
        t.FailNow()
    }
    someVar = SomethingElse
}

func resetState() {
    someVar = Default
}
```

Comment: Okay then. At least this way we leave the responsibility for restoring the proper package state at the single tests itself. I'll go with `defer` since we're working with 1.13 for now. Still a bit unsatisfying to see that tests can have those kind of side effects, but if there is no other solution, we can't change that. Thanks!

Comment: No prob! Which side effects are you referring to? I don't know how the Go test library could automatically solve your issue. The library would have no reasonable way of knowing about your application-specific state. As the above comments say, shared global state in tests should be avoided, especially if you plan on parallelizing them in the future.

Comment: Well, that changing a global var affects other tests was the side effect I meant. I understand why it happens but never expected it. I thought for every test the whole package would be loaded again and all global vars would be re-initialized.