# How to make go tests independent from each other

Tags: go, testing, server

I have two Go test functions, where the execution of one, causes the other to fail.
It's fairly clear to me, that the standard http library holds some global variables or state, that persists through multiple tests. For cases like these it [was recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61107654/make-go-tests-independent-from-each-other-mutation-of-global-vars) to have some cleanup function. However I think tests should in general not be able to affect each other. It kind of defeats the point.

Minimally reproducible sample `main_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func start_server(t *testing.T) {
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("server shut down: %s\n", err.Error())
    }
}

func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    go start_server(t)
    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Second)
    <-timer.C
}

func TestB(t *testing.T) {
    go start_server(t)
    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Second)
    <-timer.C
}
```

Running both tests:

```bash
$ go test -v main_test.go
=== RUN   TestA
--- PASS: TestA (1.00s)
=== RUN   TestB
    main_test.go:12: server shut down: listen tcp :8090: bind: address already in use
--- FAIL: TestB (1.00s)
FAIL
FAIL    command-line-arguments  2.005s
FAIL
```

However when executing only the second test:

```bash
$ go test -v main_test.go -run TestB
=== RUN   TestB
--- PASS: TestB (1.00s)
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  1.006s
```

My question is, how to make the tests be executed completely independently from another? Parallelization is not a requirement.

---

The Answer:
The problem in my case was, that goroutines are not automatically killed inbetween tests. Thus they keep running in the background. I don't think that's a good design as I cannot imagine the pros outweighing the cons. Regardless we have to live with it now.

The solution is implementing graceful shutdown. Since during a panic the test fails this will also not silently break another test if one panics.

Comment: Either use a net/http/httptest.Server for each test or start the server only once (e.g. via a sync.Once).

Comment: @Volker unfortunately the httptest.Server is not an option, because this is meant to be used for integration tests. Imagine the `start_server()` as a black_box to the application that potentially also has handler functions for routes. 
Starting the server only once is problematic, because the state changes to the server would be affected by the first test, which would make tests unreliable.

Comment: Or use [http.Server.Shutdown](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Server.Shutdown) in a defer to stop the server when you're done with it.

Comment: " the httptest.Server is not an option" I don't know how you came to this conclusion, but i don't see a reason for it in "this is meant to be used for integration tests. Imagine the start_server() as a black_box to the application that potentially also has handler functions for routes"

Comment: @erik258 the http.Server.Shutdown goes in the right direction, but in case one test crashes I would expect the Shutdown defer statement to not be executed and thus agian crash the next test. 
In my understanding the net/http/httptest.Server is for mocking the server with predefined return values. Since I am trying to test against the real server (but with my own predefined _fresh_ state) on each Test run, a mock won't do.

Comment: "my understanding the net/http/httptest.Server is for mocking the server with predefined return values" your understanding is wrong.

Comment: @GRASBOCK this is not a Go problem per se. In general TCP allows only one listener per port. If your app, whatever language it's written in, attempts to spawn multiple processes all listening on the same port, it will, most likely and not unexpectedly, break.

Comment: "in case one test crashes I would expect the Shutdown defer statement to not be executed and thus agian crash the next test". Define crash.  you mean if the test panics?  A panic is going to immediately abort all tests and end the process.   [Consider this code](https://go.dev/play/p/Wgv8RQAr0yo).

Comment: @mkopriva Do I understand correctly, that you imply go isn't terminating the `go start_server(t)` across multiple tests? I would have expected `$ go test -v main_test.go` to be equivalent to `$ go test -v main_test.go -run TestA && go test -v main_test.go -run TestB` (executing tests sequentially as two different programs)

Comment: @GRASBOCK Your expectation that when the source code contains tests `T1 ... TN`, then `go test` is equivalent to `go test -run T1 && ... && go test -run TN` is mistaken. Please read the [`go test`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Test_packages) documentation to avoid making incorrect assumptions.

Comment: @GRASBOCK Note also that using `main_test.go` as the [`[packages]`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns) argument is going to cause problems in any real-world project. This is because specifying a list of one or more files as the `[packages]` argument will cause the command to try to compile ONLY those files, omitting files that, in general, contain the code to be tested. In other words the production code tested by the test will be missing from the set of explicitly provided source files and therefore the build of the test binary will fail.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for the clarification. The example here was just so that it's easy to reproduce. Still advice worth mentioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in comments, using [`net/http/httptest`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest#Server) is the best route.

It's not a "mock" server — it will do route matching, run your handlers, and more. It just won't bind to a network address to do so.

If you *really* need a network service for your use-case, then create your own `net.Listener` instead of using `http.ListenAndServe`. This lets you bind to a random, unallocated port and avoid conflicts between tests.

Your example starts a server that runs for `TestA` but is never shutdown. By the time `TestB` tries to bind to the same port, it cannot. Following one of the below approaches will fix that:

```golang
func startServerTest(t testing.TB) *http.Client {
    t.Helper()

    // Add your handler here
    srv := httptest.NewServer(nil)

    // Close the server whenever the test/sub-test finishes
    t.Cleanup(func() {
        srv.Close()
    })
    return srv.Client()
}

func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    client := startServerTest(t)

    url := "..."
    _, err := client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("could not issue request: %v", err)
    }
}

func startServerReal(t testing.TB) string {
    t.Helper()
    // port '0' means find any available port
    //
    // Use lis.Addr() to access the socket that was bound
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:0")
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("could not start server: %v", err)
        return ""
    }

    // Close the server whenever the test/sub-test finishes
    t.Cleanup(func() {
        lis.Close()
    })

    // Add your handler here
    go http.Serve(lis, nil)
    return lis.Addr().String()
}

func TestB(t *testing.T) {
    addr := startServerReal(t)
    url := url.URL{
        Scheme: "http",
        Host:   addr,
        Path:   "/",
    }

    _, err := http.Get(url.String())
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("could not issue request: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing the latter combined with a graceful shutdown. This is not really the answer, but combined with some of the comments it was one of the most helpful to understand the underlying issue and how to deal with it.